# Insatlling Virtual box on remote machine

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I have Teamviewer installed on my remote machine which i control  from my home.

Now i want to install virtualbox on remote machine. But when i install it says that there will me temporarily disconnect from internet while installing network drivers.

I want to know that is it ok to do that from remote because if internet go down then i have to physically go there to fix something.

I once had  similar thing where when i went there it was waiting for user to click yes to install that and my internet got disconnected.

Any safe way to do that

Comment: It will prompt to install the network driver and once you click yes, the connection will temporarily be dropped. then once its restored, teamviewer should come back normally. But if you really can't have it that if it goes wrong you need to be there, don't risk it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualBox installs new network drivers on your machine, which is why the network does down momentarily.  In most cases it comes right back (I've never had any problems with it not coming back and I've run the installer dozens of times), but there is no guarantee.  The other variable in this situation is TeamViewer, if it will rebind its server after the network is brought back up, and I have no idea on that one.

My suggestion would be to tell your machine to reboot in 30 minutes right before you run the installer:

```
shutdown /r /t 1800
```

If it comes right back you can cancel the shutdown:

```
shutdown /a
```

If it doesn't, you'll at least get your machine back in 30 minutes (hopefully the network will come back after reboot).